# Query find mongoose returns a document while its not $in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having issues with mongoose queries.

I am trying to check if a object with an Id is in an array of objects.

So my query is like

```
db.getCollection('adunits').find(
{_id: ObjectId("5bd9bc1ca4efae39d0b5a58e")},
    {$in : ["5bf510156c154934150ef006","5bf5309e6c154934150f00a6","5bd9b874a4efae39d0b5a58d","5bf52a876c154934150efe4a"]}

)
```

As you can see, my ObjectId("5bd9...") IS NOT in the array. But my query returns the document with ObjectId("5bd9...").
Isn't the $in operator supposed to check if the _id in parameter is IN the array?
I wish it could return me a "0 fetched documents" because the id passed isn't in the array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not right.

You can either find by id like so:

```
db.getCollection('adunits')
    .find({_id: ObjectId("5bd9bc1ca4efae39d0b5a58e")})
```

to get a single document or use $in operator like so

```
db.getCollection('adunits')
    .find({_id: { $in: ["5bf510156c154934150ef006","5bf5309e6c154934150f00a6",...]})
```

which will return documents which have one of the ids provided in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not understanding how you search $in array with a parameter "_id" given. Like my param is "  _id = ObjectId("5bd9bc1ca4efae39d0b5a58e") " so how can I search that THIS "_id" is in the array?

Comment: Well you don't need to query db if all you want is to find if the id is in an array. `["5bf510156c154934150ef006","5bf5309e6c154934150f00a6",...].indexOf('5bd9bc1ca4efae39d0b5a58e')`

Comment: I actually do, indeed my array is fetched from database. I put here an array filled for the example but I'm using something from db. So I could just compare with indexOf() ?

Answer (score 0):

You query condition finds adunits where _id = ObjectId("5bd9bc1ca4efae39d0b5a58e"), it returns the value that matches given condition. While $in operator should applied on a filed. Are you trying to achieve some thing like, find the documents that matches ids in given array.if yes , change your code to following. Visit mongodb official https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/.

```
db.getCollection('adunits').find(
 { "_id": 
       { $in: 
             [ "5bf510156c154934150ef006",
               "5bf5309e6c154934150f00a6",
               "5bd9b874a4efae39d0b5a58d",
               "5bf52a876c154934150efe4a"
            ]
      }
});
```

Comment: Alright but there is no comparison with my parameter right there? Like, i'm trying to know if an id passed in parameter (here  _id = ObjectId("5bd9bc1ca4efae39d0b5a58e") ) is in my array ($in ... []). If I do find { "_id " : ... what is the point with my param?

Comment: would you share your schema, what actually are you going to achieve.